# How to find the polynomials that define a compact Matrix Lie group from its Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-groups, polynomials, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory

Consider a compact (connected) Lie group, or more generally, a linear algebraic Lie group. Suppose we are given the Lie algebra corresponding to the Lie group.  How can we find a set of polynomial equations in terms of the matrix elements of the group elements, that uniquely define the group?

PS: I suppose this is a basic question in Invariant theory. Is there any accessible introductory text in this area, where I can find the answer to this question?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more careful in formulating your starting assumptions. SU(2,C) is a compact connected Lie group but it is not a (complex) algebraic Lie group; for that you have to go to its complexification SL(2,C). For instance, to define SU(2,C) as a subset of C^4 you have to introduce complex conjugation which is not a "polynomial operation"

Comment: Regarding your PS: there might be something like this in the idiosyncratic book of Carter-MacDonald-Segal (LMS Student Text) which is really a collection of three short lecture courses. But this would be more of a sketch/hint rather than an explicit answer to your question. I guess Chevalley's *Theory of Lie groups* should have a detailed presentation of how one passes from a compact connected Lie group to the corresponding complex algebraic group, and maybe that goes through the Lie algebra